# When does the Sheloshim period start?

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus

Does the Sheloshim period start from

- the passing?
- the interment?
- the beginning of the shiva?

If it starts from the shiva is that only if the interment already took place?

Comment: Doesn't it start when Shiva ends?

Comment: i mean as far as for siyumim

Comment: I don't know what that means

Comment: @DoubleAA i was trying to figure out when to make a siyum for the shloshim

Comment: I don't know what that means. Make a Siyum when you finish learning something significant.

Comment: Many people have a custom to learn something לעילוי נשמת the נפטר, and they try to specifically do so either during the Shloshim period or at least before the first yahrtzeit.

Comment: @Uber_Chacham Do you see why including that information would be useful to someone trying to answer the question? Maybe the end of Shloshim for this custom is calculated differently. Maybe the Siyum should happen actually just after Shloshim. Etc. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166155 Ask for what you want to know, include all relevant background information, and don't oversimplify for fear of missing the point. You're lucky in this case that the person who answered below noticed your comment. In general important info should always  be in the q not in comments.

Comment: I agree, which is why I commented and added this. However, notice, this was not my question; it was @Ibber Chochem's. Having similar names can get quite confusing. I would also note that while the siyum should most probably happen after the end of the shloshim, as it is a simcha, he is probably asking about when he has to finish the learning by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear from the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in סימן רד - אימתי מתחילה האבלות (and other places) that the Shloshim count begins at the same time the Shiva begins.

E.g.:

> מִי שֶׁשָּׁמַע שֶׁמֵּת לוֹ מֵת, וּכְבָר הִתְפַּלְּלוּ הַצִּבּוּר עַרְבִית וַעֲדַיִן הוּא יוֹם, אִם הוּא עֲדַיִן לֹא הִתְפַּלֵּל עַרְבִית, אֵינוֹ נִגְרָר אַחַר הַצִּבּוּר, וְאוֹתוֹ הַיּוֹם עוֹלֶה לוֹ. אֲבָל אִם הִתְפַּלֵּל עַרְבִית, שׁוּב אֵינוֹ עוֹלֶה לוֹ אוֹתוֹ הַיּוֹם, **וּמוֹנֶה שִׁבְעָה וּשְׁלשִׁים מִיּוֹם הַמָּחֳרָת**.‏

This is true for a regular case where the mourners start sitting Shiva right after the burial or when the coffin leaves town.

However, in the case of the burial being on חֹל הַמּוֹעֵד, or on the 2nd day of Yom Tov, then the Shloshim begins on the day of the burial, and the Shiva only begins after the Chag is over, as the Kitzur says in סימן ריט - דין אבלות בשבת ויום טוב.

> אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵין אֲבֵלוּת בְּיוֹם טוֹב וּבְחֹל הַמּוֹעֵד, וַאֲפִלּוּ גְזֵרַת שְׁלֹשִׁים אֵין בָּהֶם, וּמֻתָּר לוֹ לִלְבּוֹשׁ בְּגָדִים מְגֹהָצִים, מִכָּל מָקוֹם כֵּיוָן דְאָסוּר בָּהֶם בְּגִלּוּחַ מֵחֲמַת הַמּוֹעֵד (כְּדִלְעֵיל סִימָן קד סָעִיף יא), לָכֵן עוֹלִין לְמִנְיַן שְׁלֹשִׁים, וּמוֹנֶה שְׁלֹשִׁים מִיּוֹם הַקְּבוּרָה. וְיוֹם שְׁמִינִי עֲצֶרֶת, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא רֶגֶל בִּפְנֵי עַצְמוֹ, מִכָּל מָקוֹם כֵּיוָן שֶׁלֹּא הִתְחִיל עֲדַיִן בַּאֲבֵלוּת, אֵינוֹ מְבַטֵּל, וְגַם בְמִנְיַן הַשְׁלֹשִׁים אֵינוֹ נִמְנֶה רַק לְיוֹם אֶחָד. ‏

So, since a mourner cannot join a *party* during the Shloshim as it says in the Kitzur in סימן ריב - דברים האסורים משום שמחה, a *Shloshim Siyum* can be made on day 31 and onwards.

> אֵינוֹ רַשַׁאי לְהַזְמִין אֲחֵרִים אוֹ לְהִזָּמֵן עִם אֲחֵרִים. לֹא יִשְׁלַח מָנוֹת לַאֲחֵרִים, וַאֲחֵרִים לֹא יִשְׁלְחוּ לוֹ, כָּל שְׁלֹשִׁים. וְהוּא הַדִּין כָּל שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר חֹדֶשׁ עַל אָבִיו וְאִמּוֹ. וּבְשַׁבָּת, תַּלְיָא בְמִנְהָג דִּלְעֵיל סִימָן רי סָעִיף ח. ‏